# CABasicAnimation disabling any touch activity within animated layer

Tags: iphone, touch, opacity, layer, cabasicanimation

```
- (void)fadeOutStuff
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    anim.delegate = self;
    anim.duration = 0.25f;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    [self.searchList.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"animationOpacity"];
}
```

I have this code to simply animate an object in and out, and after the animation is complete, the layer is not touchable. Is the animation process setting the layer down a level/index? I can still touch elements behind the animated layer, but not the animated layer itself. Am I missing a setting? Am I going about animation the wrong way, based on this code?

Answer (score 1):

I figure this out, and the property fillMode is mainly responsible for disabling touch events in animated objects. Do not use it if whatever you're animating needs to handle touch events. Basically, the workaround I used was removed the fillMode property, and set the final stage of the animation manually after adding the animation to the layer

```
[self.searchList.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"animationOpacity"];
[self.searchList.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:endingOpacityValue forKey:@"opacity"]];
```

Comment: I am facing same problem.....and I tried the way you did...still its not able to detect the touches.....Can you please provide me your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, hidden objects won't receive touches. I don't know if the applies if it's just opacity set to zero, but try seeing what happens if you do it to just 0.01f instead of all the way to 0.

By the way, I don't know if it's a typo or not, but you set `anim.fromValue` twice, and you don't set `anim.toValue`.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the timely response. I fixed the typo, and tried setting the view to an alpha of 0.01f at initialization. Is that the same as a hidden object? The view is still not receiving any touches.

Comment: I recall I had the same issue with position transitions as well. I have yet to get touchable views to work with animations.

Comment: OK, I just added the subview without animating it and its opacity set to 1.0f, and I can see it, but still it won't react to touch events. Am I going about adding subviews the wrong way? What's the best practice for implementing subviews?